# Definition Class not found : com.google.common.primitives.Longs

Tags: java, android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, plugins

I made a jar plugin for Unity with Android Studio. My plugin use com.google.common.primitives.Longs. But the class definition is not found. The console of Unity shows me these errors:

```
2021/08/09 10:09:43.214 4060 4081 Error Unity AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/common/primitives/Longs;
2021/08/09 10:09:43.214 4060 4081 Error Unity java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/common/primitives/Longs;
2021/08/09 10:09:43.214 4060 4081 Error Unity   at com.fitimmersion.plugin.FitImmersionPlugin.removeFromDownloads(FitImmersionPlugin.java:570)
2021/08/09 10:09:43.214 4060 4081 Error Unity   at com.fitimmersion.plugin.FitImmersionPlugin.checkDownloadProgress(FitImmersionPlugin.java:463)
2021/08/09 10:09:43.214 4060 4081 Error Unity   at com.fitimmersion.plugin.FitImmersionPlugin.getDownloadProgress(FitImmersionPlugin.java:411)
2021/08/09 10:09:43.214 4060 4081 Error Unity   at com.fitimmersion.plugin.FitImmersionPlugin.exportGetDownloadProgress(FitImmersionPlugin.java:402)
2021/08/09 10:09:43.214 4060 4081 Error Unity   at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
2021/08/09 10:09:43.214 4060 4081 Error Unity   at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.access$300(Unknown Source:0)
2021/08/09 10:09:43.214 4060 4081 Error Unity   at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source:95)
2021/08/09 10:09:43.214 4060 4081 Error Unity   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
2021/08/09 10:09:43.214 4060 4081 Error Unity   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
2021/08/09 10:09:43.214 4060 4081 Error Unity   at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source:20)
2021/08/09 10:09:43.214 4060 4081 Error Unity Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.prim
```

I think that an implementation is missing in the dependencies of my gradle file.
What I can do to make the class definition to be found ?

Thanks for answers !

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add this dependencies files to Assets->Plugin->Android folder in unity or Alternatively you can manually resolve this dependencies in unity using [this plugin](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver)   Just add this plugin to project and then Follow instruction

Comment: Thanks a lot !
This Unity plugin is useful !
I will try it however I searched for the moment a solution in Android Studio without using Unity.